# I want to integrate image upload API in react native using react-native-image-crop-picker and in the image response I get only path not uri

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
const uploadFile = async () => {
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    cropping: true,
    mediaType: "photo",
    forceJpg: true,
  }).then((option) => {
    console.log(option);
    setImage(option.path);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
      name: option?.filename,
      type: option?.mime,
      uri: option?.path,
    });
    axios.post(
      "Api_URL /provider/UploadFile",
      { file: data },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: authToken,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I'm new in this field so I don't have too much knowledge about it hope for the best Thank you